# From terminal in ubuntu, change ulimit for file descriptor number

Tags: ubuntu, uwsgi, ulimit

Fron the terminal I am trying to change the number of file descriptions open and they will not stick. How, from the terminal do I change the ulimit?  Per the below, when I run uwsgi from the terminal, fd are at 1024.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ uwsgi --loop gevent --socket :3031 --wsgi-file /home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbAsyncServers/bottleServer.py --master --async 100 --listen 300 --processes 1
*** Starting uWSGI 1.2.1 (64bit) on [Sat May 12 05:24:25 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.5.2 on 11 May 2012 03:42:53
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /tmp
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
async fd table size: 1024
allocated 103200 bytes (100 KB) for 100 cores per worker.
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :3031 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:37:12)  [GCC 4.5.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xd9bfd0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 300 connections
*** Operational MODE: async ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 8 seconds on interpreter 0xd9bfd0 pid: 17688 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17688)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17742, cores: 100)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x4503f0] ***
!!! Running gevent without threads IS NOT recommended, enable them with --enable-threads !!!
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to change it?

Comment: I tried the following - ulimit 60000

Comment: Let's try some more detail.  You are running this in the same shell, and you are verifying that it actually did something first?  Please provide full detail of exactly what sequence of commands you are running and where.

Comment: 1) in the SAME shell ulimit 60000 then 2) uwsgi --loop gevent --socket :3031 --wsgi-file...

Comment: And you tested that `ulimit` output changed first?  In any case, nonroot probably can't raise it that high; study the difference between soft and hard limits, and who can change each.

Comment: I have the very same issue, and I can assure `ulimit` change the limit, but the output of uwsgi is always the same...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when trying to raise the number of file descriptors for Nginx. I had to change `nofile` in */etc/security/limits.conf* for the www-data user:

```
www-data    hard    nofile    16384
www-data    soft    nofile    16384
```

After this change ulimit still showed a limit of 1024. The solution was to enable *pam_limits* in */etc/pam.d/su*. I just uncommented the line:

```
session    required    pam_limits.so
```

Changing this value didn't require a restart, I just logged in as www-data again. Now, running `ulimit -a` revealed the value `16384`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the sake of future googlers: there is apparently a tool called `prlimit` that can change the limits without start but still after years it is not in util-linux. There is a small utility [here](http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/ulimit#set_nofile_limit) that will work on any newish kernel.