# Changing ulimit on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, file, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ulimit

Is there a way to increase the ulimit -n (open files) for an Amazon EC2 instance? I am running an amazon m3.2xlarge ubuntu instance for testing purposes. The ulimit -Hn is 4096 but I need over 10k. I have even tried temporarily getting higher instance types but no luck.

I have googled around for quite a while but there are only topics on this that are a few years old. Most suggest changing the limits.conf file found in /etc/security/limits.conf but the limit is read only so I cannot change permissions.

Are there any alternative ways to change this ?

Edit - my etc/security/limits.conf file

```
#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
root            soft    nofile          16500
root            hard    nofile          16500
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up the instance or you have sudo privileges, you can change those configuration files. Just prepend your command to open the file with `sudo`, (example `sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf`).

Comment: thanks! I was able to edit the file but it still has not helped changing the ulimit unfortunately

Comment: I believe the config settings are only used at boot. Each version of Linux handles this a bit differently, but you will probably need to reboot to take advantage of the new limits.

Comment: hmm I rebooted a couple of times. Maybe my limits.conf file is not correct, Ive included it in the post

Comment: I think the `#` is treating the line as a comment.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might have been the case when checking out some of the other files but even uncommenting those two specifically & rebooting, the maximum is still 4096 (no change)

Comment: Finally got it following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558876/from-terminal-in-ubuntu-change-ulimit-for-file-descriptor-number?rq=1 Needed to uncomment something from /parm.d/su

Comment: Also note that, per the comment in the top of the file on my EC2 instances, the settings in this file only apply to "users logged in via PAM".

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue recently and resulted in editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` in my [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) script. It ended up looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "*   hard  nofile  65535" | tee --append /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "*   soft  nofile  65535" | tee --append /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Note that the 'user' for the limits.conf is `*`, meaning all users will have `65535` as their limit.

Comment: gorbot: Did this actually work for you, editing the /etc/security/limits.conf file on instance launch? I was under the impression that you would need to somehow reboot the instance after making the edits in order for changes to that file to take effect