# Logstash (ELK) in an LXC Container - ulimit error

Tags: logstash, lxc, ulimit

I've got ELK set up in an LXC container on 3.13 (Ubuntu 14.04.2) and I assume that it's configured correctly (no errors in logs or otherwise). That being said, when ever I try to fire up LogStash, I get the following error
`/etc/init.d/logstash: 55: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)`

Yes, I'm root when I run the command. Same error running `service start logstash`

Despite the error, I see `logstash started.` right after. But, a quick netstat clearly shows that Logstash isn't listening (Yes, I've tried shoving logs at it anyway to no avail)...

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6523/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      5890/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      5890/java       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           303/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44889           0.0.0.0:*                           303/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::2274                 :::*                                303/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::54328                :::*                                5890/java
```

Thoughts on how to fix this? I'm reasonably certain that it's an LXC issue due to `ulimit` puking, but I'm not sure how to remedy.

Edit: Further reading tells me that it is indeed a ulimit issue. I've gone ahead upped my user limits to more than 16384 (what logstash init wants), but I'm still getting the issue after restarting the container. My `/etc/security/limits.conf` has the following lines appended

```
user          soft    nofile          24576
user          hard    nofile          24576
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but anyone who has the same issue may well end up here as I did.

The answer for me was here: [From terminal in ubuntu, change ulimit for file descriptor number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558876/from-terminal-in-ubuntu-change-ulimit-for-file-descriptor-number)

Specifically, making sure that /etc/pam.d/su contained the line (I just needed to uncomment it in Ubuntu 14.04):

```
session    required    pam_limits.so
```

Then logout and login and it worked.

Comment: I don't currently have an LXC box to test this, but I do appreciate your feedback here! Having done some reading, I suspect that you're right in this being my issue as well. Cheers!